# What technique is the last step of this integration?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So, in my book, *Circuit Analysis, Second Edition* by Cunningham and Stuller the give the following integration for the the energy absorbed by a capacitor in circuit.  Remember $p=vi$ (power absorbed = voltage * current) and capacitor voltage is $i_{ab}=C\frac{d}{dt}v_{ab}$, (momentary current is equal to the momentary change in voltage across the terminals $a$ and $b$.) The derevation goes like this:
$$w(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tv({\lambda})i(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda\\=\int_{-\infty}^{t}v(\lambda)C\left[\frac{d}{d\lambda}v({\lambda})\right]\mathrm{d}{\lambda}$$

and proceeds to the last step, which I do not understand.

$$\int_{v(-\infty)}^{v(t)}Cv(\lambda)dv({\lambda}) = \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)$$

I have no idea what technique is used to do this.  In fact, the syntax $\int dx({\lambda})$ is totally unfamiliar to me; I don't even know where to go to look that up.  Also, I do not follow the integration ie, how they get the part of the line $\frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)$.  Worse, I'm not totally sure how they changed the bounds of integration.  The first two lines are easy to follow.

A thousand thank yous for any guidance I may receive.

Comment: I've never seen that notation before, but I'm thinking they made a substitution to $v(\lambda)$ based on the change of the bounds of integration.

Comment: If C here is a constant, then maybe they are using integration by parts, with $u=cv(\lambda)$ and $dV=v^{\prime}(\lambda)d\lambda$. This would give $w(t)=[cv(\lambda)^{2}]_{-\infty}^{t}-w(t)$, so $w(t)=\frac{1}{2}[c(v(\lambda))^{2}]_{-\infty}^{t}$ (and maybe $v(-\infty)=0$)